# if record is existing Update or else insert a new record based on corresponding enteries

Tags: java

I have a table as

```
CREATE TABLE `category` (
  `category_id` int(11) ,
  `T1` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `T2` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `T3` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `T4` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `T5` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
 )



mysql> select * from category;
+-------------+----------+-------------+---------------+------+------+
| category_id | T1       | T2          | T3            | T4   | T5   |
+-------------+----------+-------------+---------------+------+------+
|         145 | Pop Corn | Regular Tub | Plain Salted  | NULL | NULL |
|         150 | Pop Corn | Buckets     | Plain Salted  | NULL | NULL | 
|         151 | Pop Corn | Jumbo       | Plain Salted  | NULL | NULL | 
|         152 | Pop Corn | Regular Tub | Butter Scotch | NULL | NULL | 
|         153 | Pop Corn | Regular Tub | Tomoto Tango  | NULL | NULL | 
|         154 | Pop Corn | Buckets     | Butter Scotch | NULL | NULL | 
|         222 | Pop Corn | NULL        | NULL          | NULL | NULL |
| +-------------+----------+-------------+---------------+------+-----
```

My Logic

```
String reqstr="Pop Corn@Small@Test";
String values[] = reqstr.split("@");

            else  if(values.length==3)
            {

                sqlselect = "select category_id from category where T1 = ? AND T2 IS NULL AND T3 IS NULL AND T4 IS NULL"  ;
                    selectpst = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sqlselect);
                    selectpst.setString(1, values[0]);
                    resultset = selectpst.executeQuery();
                    if(resultset.next())
                    {
                            sql = "update category set T3 = '"+values[2]+"' T2 = '"+values[1]+"' where T1 ='"+values[0]+"'   
                            updateStatement.executeUpdate(sql);     

// similarly check for T2 , T3 , T4 also 

                    }

                    else
                    {

                    // Insert logic here 

                    }



            }
```

Can this logic be modified to be more efficieient ??

The problem i am facing is that for example in this case as Pop Corn is already existing , it should update that one , or else it should insert new one

Similarly if Pop Corn Small is existing it should update that one or else insert a new record

Comment: selectpst.setString(1, values[0]); isn't the first argument supposed to be 0?

Comment: combine them into single query.